# Generate matrices for pairs of values in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 3D array (a 2D array of vectors), of which I want to transform each vector with a rotation matrix. The rotations are in two separate 2D arrays of radians angle values called `cols` and `rows`.

I've been able to have NumPy compute the angles for me already, without a Python loop. Now I'm looking for a way to have NumPy generate the rotation matrices, too, hopefully resulting in a great performance boost.

```
size = img.shape[:2]

# Create an array that assigns each pixel the percentage of
# the correction (value between -1 and 1, distributed linearly).
cols = np.array([np.arange(size[1]) for __ in range(size[0])])   / (size[1] - 1) * 2 - 1
rows = np.array([np.arange(size[0]) for __ in range(size[1])]).T / (size[0] - 1) * 2 - 1

# Atan distribution based on F-number and Sensor size.
cols = np.arctan(sh * cols / (2 * f))
rows = np.arctan(sv * rows / (2 * f))

### This is the loop that I would like to remove and find a
### clever way to make NumPy do the same operation natively.
for i in range(size[0]):
  for j in range(size[1]):
    ah = cols[i,j]
    av = rows[i,j]

    # Y-rotation.
    mat = np.matrix([
      [ np.cos(ah), 0, np.sin(ah)],
      [0, 1, 0],
      [-np.sin(ah), 0, np.cos(ah)]
    ])

    # X-rotation.
    mat *= np.matrix([
      [1, 0, 0],
      [0, np.cos(av), -np.sin(av)],
      [0, np.sin(av),  np.cos(av)]
    ])

    img[i,j] = img[i,j] * mat

return img
```

Is there any clever way to rewrite the loop in NumPy operations?

Comment: One of the rotation matrix should use `av`?

Comment: @kennytm That is correct, thanks for spotting this error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Let's assume the shape of `img` be `(a, b, 3)`.)

Firstly, `cols` and `rows` does not need to be fully expanded to `(a, b)` (you could write `cols[j]` instead of `cols[i,j]`). And they can be easy generated using [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
cols = np.linspace(-1, 1, size[1])   # shape: (b,)
rows = np.linspace(-1, 1, size[0])   # shape: (a,)

cols = np.arctan(sh * cols / (2*f))
rows = np.arctan(sv * rows / (2*f))
```

Then we get precalculate the components of the matrices.

```
# shape: (b,)
cos_ah = np.cos(cols)
sin_ah = np.sin(cols)   
zeros_ah = np.zeros_like(cols)
ones_ah = np.ones_like(cols)

# shape: (a,)
cos_av = np.cos(rows)
sin_av = np.sin(rows)   
zeros_av = np.zeros_like(rows)
ones_av = np.ones_like(rows)
```

And then construct the rotation matrices:

```
# shape: (3, 3, b)
y_mat = np.array([
    [cos_ah, zeros_ah, sin_ah],
    [zeros_ah, ones_ah, zeros_ah],
    [-sin_ah, zeros_ah, cos_ah],
])

# shape: (3, 3, a)
x_mat = np.array([
    [ones_av, zeros_av, zeros_av],
    [zeros_av, cos_av, -sin_av],
    [zeros_av, sin_av, cos_av],
])
```

Now let's see. If we have a loop we would write:

```
for i in range(size[0]):
    for j in range(size[1]):
        img[i, j, :] = img[i, j, :] @ y_mat[:, :, j] @ x_mat[:, :, i]
```

or, if we expand out the matrix multiplications:

[image: img[i,j,n] = sum(img[i,j,k]*y_mat[k,m,j]*x_mat[m,n,i] for m = 1 to 3 for n = 1 to 3)]

This can be handled nicely using [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) (note the *i*,*j*,*k*,*m*,*n* corresponds exactly like the equation above):

```
img = np.einsum('ijk,kmj,mni->ijn', img, y_mat, x_mat)
```

---

To summarize:

```
size = img.shape[:2]

cols = np.linspace(-1, 1, size[1])   # shape: (b,)
rows = np.linspace(-1, 1, size[0])   # shape: (a,)

cols = np.arctan(sh * cols / (2*f))
rows = np.arctan(sv * rows / (2*f))

cos_ah = np.cos(cols)
sin_ah = np.sin(cols)   
zeros_ah = np.zeros_like(cols)
ones_ah = np.ones_like(cols)

cos_av = np.cos(rows)
sin_av = np.sin(rows)   
zeros_av = np.zeros_like(rows)
ones_av = np.ones_like(rows)

y_mat = np.array([
    [cos_ah, zeros_ah, sin_ah],
    [zeros_ah, ones_ah, zeros_ah],
    [-sin_ah, zeros_ah, cos_ah],
])

x_mat = np.array([
    [ones_av, zeros_av, zeros_av],
    [zeros_av, cos_av, -sin_av],
    [zeros_av, sin_av, cos_av],
])

return np.einsum('ijk,kmj,mni->ijn', img, y_mat, x_mat)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this elegant solution! I haven't used NumPy much until recently, your explanations about generating `cols` and `rows` is also very valuable. :)

Comment: I'll also have to spend some time breaking down and understanding `np.einsum()` and the formula you wrote down.